# React native typescript issue

Tags: react-native

When I create a react native app from the command line using create-react-native-app <project_name>, it gets configured in typescript format, with the base app file as App.tsx, which I want it in Javascript form.
Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You should use this command

`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

instead of this

`npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript`

Comment: It's fine! I initialised the project using Expo CLI